# no output tracing appears in Visual studio output window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

i have been using several ways to Trace output inside Visual Studio 2008 output window but with no mean, i tried:

```
   `cout<<"AAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB";

LPCWSTR str=_T("jdhakjsdk");
OutputDebugString(str);

printf("jdhakjshkajshdkjashdk");`
```

but nothing appears!! is it true that the output window might be locked??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you get no debug output (remember that `OutputDebugString` only works in debug mode with a debugger attached). However, in MFC, you typically use the [TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyz8787%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) macro:

```
TRACE(_T("Data: %s\n"), pszData);
```